# Cloudformation: substitute variable in map key

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I have a role defined like this:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"


Parameters:
  AWSAccountId:
    Type: String

  OidcProvider:
    Type: String

  AppNamespace:
    Type: String
 
 AppServiceAccountName:
    Type: String


Resources:
  CloudWatchRole:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          -
            Effect: "Allow"
            Principal:
              Federated:
                - !Join ["", [ "arn:aws:iam::", !Ref AWSAccountId, ":oidc-provider/", !Ref OidcProvider ] ]
            Action:
              - "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity"
            Condition:
              StringEquals:
                !Sub ${OidcProvider}:sub: "system:serviceaccount:${AppNamespace}:${AppServiceAccountName}"
```

My challenge is how to substitute parameters in the StringEquals section. Everything works in the Federated block. But in the StringEquals block I couldn't get join or sub to work.

With the code as is, I get error message:

```
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateStack operation: 
Template format error[/Resources/CloudWatchRole/Properties/AssumeRolePolicyDocument/
Statement/0/Condition/StringEquals] map keys must be strings; received a map instead
```

So, I guess my issue is how to substitute variables in the keys of a map. UserData didn't help either.

Comment: What exactly should be `StringEquals` as a result?

Comment: StringEquals is a map like here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_condition_operators.html

Comment: What is `OidcProvider`? Sadly your question lacks details and is unclear.

Comment: Sure. OidcProvider is a parameter. Just as is AppNamespace and AppServiceAccountName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is on `Federated` not on `StringEquals`.
`Federated` value needs to be `string` but you define it as `Map`. Please remove `-` before `!Join`.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"

Parameters:
  AWSAccountId:
    Type: String
  OidcProvider:
    Type: String
  AppNamespace:
    Type: String
  AppServiceAccountName:
    Type: String

Resources:
  CloudWatchRole:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument: !Sub
        - |
          {
            "Version": "2012-10-17",
            "Statement": [
                {
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Principal": {
                        "Federated": "${IamOidcProviderArn}"
                    },
                    "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
                    "Condition": {
                        "StringEquals": {
                            "${OidcProvider}:sub": "system:serviceaccount:${AppNamespace}:${AppServiceAccountName}"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
          }
        - IamOidcProviderArn: !Join
          - ''
          - - 'arn:aws:iam::'
            - !Ref AWSAccountId
            - ':oidc-provider/'
            - !Ref OidcProvider
          OidcProvider: !Ref OidcProvider
          AppNamespace: !Ref AppNamespace
          AppServiceAccountName: !Ref AppServiceAccountName
```

Comment: If I remove StringEquals everything works fine. The error is: An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateStack operation: Template format error: [/Resources/CloudWatchRole/Properties/AssumeRolePolicyDocument/Statement/0/Condition/StringEquals] map keys must be strings; received a map instead.

Comment: I have tested with code above in my comment, it works well